# What is the difference between embedded reactive web server and embedded web server in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
  .web(WebApplicationType.REACTIVE).run(args)
```

In my project we are using google kubernetes engine (gke) and spring webflux for this which one is better.

What are the pros and cons of WebApplicationType.REACTIVE in Spring Webflux?

When to use embedded REACTIVE Webserver and embedded Webserver?

Comment: One is reactive the other isn't. You only need to specify this if you have both the WebFlux and MVC classes on your classpath. Else it will be auto-detected.

Comment: I have Webflux only in my project

Answer (score 1):

There are three possible types of web applications in spring:

**NONE** - The application should not run as a web application and should not start an embedded web server

**SERVLET** - The application should run as a servlet-based web application and should start an embedded servlet web server.

**REACTIVE** - The application should run as a reactive web application and should start an embedded reactive web server.

If you use Spring WebFlux you should choose REACTIVE. The reactive web server is based on the Reactor Netty framework, which is a non-blocking, event-driven server.

If you use Spring MVC you should choose SERVLET.